# How would I compile a project with Objective-C ParseKit on Ubuntu?

Tags: objective-c, ubuntu, compilation, parsekit

I am working on a project for which we will be using ParseKit. Currently I have no access to a Mac, but want to start working on some initial testing and parsing for an application on Ubuntu.

I would assume this should require no more than a console app to test some parsing with ParseKit, but maybe it's more complicated than that.

I have GNUstep installed and can compile an Objective-C program with a GNUmakefile (allowing me to use `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` and all the 'NS' objects).

Is it possible to compile and run a project along with ParseKit without XCode on Ubuntu? If it is possible then how would I go about this? Do I need to move the ParseKit source files to a specific folder or change the source in any way? Do I need to include all the ParseKit files in the makefile?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell you is that you cannot build ParseKit with GNUstep Foundation alone, at least not without some source modifications, that may include trying to install gnustep-corebase for CoreFoundation types. You will also need to bypass OS-specific headers like TargetConditionals.h or AvailabilityMacros.h. I am not sure how much hacks you will need to make the original source more portable. If this really worth it you will have to write a simple GNUmakefile, so you can start compiling the project and fix things.